# Clientsided data-cleaning and analysis with sturts2

Tags: javascript, struts2, client-side, weka

right now I'm trying to implement a webapp that does data cleaning and analysis and I have already a prototype written in Java. For the analysis part I tend to use WEKA (http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/). Because of performance reasons I thought it might be a good idea to let the client do most of the work. I started to learn struts2 and I have no experience using JavaScript. My questions are:

1. Is struts2 the right choise for this task?
2. Should I write a Java Applet or can it also be done by Java Script?

I don't have enough experience nor have I found a good solution searching the internet. Can you perhaps post some tutorials or websites that might help me with my questions?

Comment: Java is to JavaScript as car is to carpet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it client-side then you need to distribute an app, or use an applet. JavaScript is not Java, and you can't use the browser's JavaScript to run Weka.

If you want to do it client-side, why are you trying to implement a web app?

Struts 2 is fine, but it depends on what you're actually doing. There are many JVM-based web frameworks: Spring MVC, Grails, Play, etc. If you want to move analysis onto the client it probably doesn't matter *what* framework you use, but it's impossible to say from the info you've provided.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the quick answer.

I like the idea of a web app because with java script I have so many opportunities to visualize the data.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the quick answer.

I have given some further thought of what I want to implement and what I need for this. It all comes down to this:
A powerful data analysis and data cleaning tool with many visualization opportunities that runs on the client-side.

I think a Java Applet can do client-sided analysis and cleaning but does not have good visualization opportunities(?). I found many visualization techniques for JavaScript but as you said I can't use Weka. With a web based solution I can combine the two things but it will be server-sided, right?